# Play a sound when AppleScript is done

Tags: applescript

I have no idea how to use AppleScript, how I got my little bash script working in the first place was beyond me. I'm currently using an AppleScript to run my bash script and it works fantastically. It is below.

```
do shell script "/Users/john/Scripts/screenshot -i --delete"
```

Now the bash script its referring to is that it will take a screenshot and upload it to my server, however;

I want it to play a sound when its done, how can I go about doing this? AppleScript is beyond my knowledge...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use *afplay* :

```
do shell script "afplay /Users/john/Sounds/vengabus.aiff"
```

or i like to use text to speech:

```
say "Finished!"
```

Answer (score 13):

The notification center (probably OS X 10.9.x only) can display messages with a sound.

```
set variableWithSoundName to "Glass"
display notification "Upload complete" with title "Screenshot" subtitle "Status" sound name variableWithSoundName

-- "sound name" is the name of a sound located in "~/Library/Sounds"
--  or "/System/Library/Sounds"
```

The `display notification` command is from the `StandardAdditions`.

(…and there is also the command `beep` which plays the default alert sound and takes the number of "beeps" as argument)

Answer (score 11):

Just to complement @adamh and @DigiMonk's excellent answers:

Good old `beep` can do the job if the default sound will do:

```
beep  # beep once
```

If once isn't enough, simply specify the desired number of beeps as an argument:

```
beep 2 # beep twice.
```

Incidentally, `beep`, `say`, and `display notification` are all defined in the `User Interaction` suite of dictionary `StandardAdditions.sdef`. To see these definitions, select `File > Open Dictionary...` in AppleScript Editor, and, in the list that pops up, select `StandardAdditions.osax`.

Comment: One thing to note about `beep` is it will flash the screen if you have **Accessibility > Audio > Flash the screen when an alert sound occurs** checked.

Answer (score 2):

You can play a random sound too!

```
do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/" & some item of paragraphs of ((do shell script "ls /System/Library/Sounds/")) ---random sound
```

Answer (score 0):

Alfred 2 to assign global shortcut to do shell script "afplay /Users/john/Sounds/vengabus.aiff" + Spark for lion is good combo.